# Passing enumeration with exception - Java

Tags: java

Is it possible to pass back an `enumeration` when `throwing` a custom `exception`?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it's (IMO) a *terrible* design. You can give your `Exception` a field of your enumeration type, pass the instance you want when your construct your custom `Exception` instance and add an accessor for it.

```
throw new MyException(MyEnum.MY_VALUE);
```

And, when you catch it,

```
} catch (MyException me) {
    MyEnum theEnum = me.getMyEnum();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hey Elliott, thanks for the quick reply.  I would really love to know your opinion as to why this is bad design.

Comment: Well, wouldn't the receiving end need to know this Enum ? So it would have to be declared twice